# How to achieve "as if" multiple exes running from one exe in C#

Tags: c#

Can you let me know whether following tasks is achievable or not, if yes then how, if no then why.

I have got mailing function written in C#, i need to send 50 mails at one shot. Now i can achieve this by two ways either run 50 exes at one time or by implementing threading concept in single program.

But as expected threading concept is not giving me result or can say performance as i am getting by running multiple exes. Can you help me by giving suggestion or concept for running one program and get the performance of running multiple exes.

Comment: As expected? I'd like to see your numbers that prove launching an entire new process gets code done faster than just a single thread.

Comment: Why to run 50 Exes..? Add a Background Worker and Using loop send that email with List Collection Email Addresses

Comment: Sorry Andrew Barber but I don't think so it has got too many possible answers or good answers would be long, because answer to my question is only Yes or No. If yes then what could be the logic behind it, and i think logic will not take some much lines, if no then why is again will be short answer.

Comment: I have developed C# code to stand my question but getting no way to upload the same, can you guide me?

Answer (score 1):

IF you want to send same emails to 50 different email addresses ( 50 emails) then you should be able to do it by specifying all your email addresses as BCC in your code. or even just specify them as comma seperated values in "TO" email address.

You can loop upto 50 times to send 50 different emails to 50 different addresses by looping a list which contains an object of type EmailContent having
FromAddress
ToAddress
Body

Hope that helps